# Learning bash: Append a line to list of files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a list of files of which I want to add a line to the end of the file. I cannot find the correct way to do it:

```
find . | grep filexxx | xargs << echo "attribute=0000"
```

Does not seem to work, unfortunately. Without writing a script, which oneliner command would do it?

thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use find's option: -exec like this:

```
find . -type f -name "file*" -exec bash -c 'echo "your line" >> $1' -- {} \;
```

you need to change file* to match files you are looking for.

There is also another possibility:

```
find . -type f | while read file; do echo "your line" >> $file ; done
```

you can pipe find to grep or use -name in the above

edit:

as suggested by [knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl) in comments, you would have problems with the above one liner if your filename contains new line character.. and solution provided by [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson):

```
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do ...
```

Comment: Note that `find|while` will cause problems if your filenames contain newline characters.

Comment: @knittl: Correct; to avoid trouble, use `find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do ...` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Or use a simple loop:

```
for f in *txt; do echo "yada" >> "${f}"; done
```

Comment: That will not work for files in subdirs. Also, you don't have to double quote the `${f}`.

Comment: I did not know that was a requirement, OP only said "a list of files", nothing about depth there. I usually quote when interpolating variables in Bash because of space side effects. the `while read` example in another comment would actually be more appropriate to handle spaces in files correctly.

Comment: I don't know if it's a requirement or not, I just clarified :-) In case OP expect it to go into subdirs.

Comment: @bos, you certainly do quote $f, or it will break for files with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to do this. wisent's answer is one. Here is another, perhaps more intuitive, even if it spawns more processes:

```
for fname in $(find . | grep filexxx) ; do echo "attribute=0000" >> $fname ; done
```